# How to make policykit/polkit ask for YES or NO prompt instead of password?

Tags: arch-linux, password, manjaro, plasma, polkit

How to make policykit/polkit ask for YES or NO confirmation instead of asking for the password?

I don't want to remove the polkit prompt, just convert it to a confirmation dialog.
Setting the password to "yes" is not an acceptable solution.

I'm using KDE Plasma on Manjaro.

Comment: Dumping the thread.

Comment: What does that mean?